Docker for amd64 but not for arm(mac) with Microsoft SQL Server ODBC driver
I have following docker file
`# Use the official Python 3.9 slim image as the base
FROM python:3.9-slim

`# Install necessary packages and setup Microsoft SQL Server ODBC driver repository for Debian 11 (Bullseye)`
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    iputils-ping \
    curl \
    gnupg2 \
    apt-transport-https \
    unixodbc \
    unixodbc-dev \
    libgssapi-krb5-2 && \
    curl -fsSL https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/microsoft-archive-keyring.gpg && \
    echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/microsoft-archive-keyring.gpg] https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/11/prod bullseye main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

`# Install the ODBC Driver 18 without mssql-tools
RUN apt-get update && \
    ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql18 && \
    echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc && \
    . ~/.bashrc`

I have no issues building this docker file on my mac but when I try to build it for amd64 I get following error
  18 |     # Install the ODBC Driver 18 without mssql-tools
  19 | >>> RUN apt-get update && \
  20 | >>>     ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql18 && \
  21 | >>>     echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc && \
  22 | >>>     . ~/.bashrc
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get update &&     ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql18 &&     echo 'export PATH=\"$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin\"' >> ~/.bashrc &&     . ~/.bashrc" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100

Does anyone know how to solve this?
I have tried to change the code according to ChatGPT and also searched on the internet but can't find any solution

The error message is probably further up in the output.

If you docker run -it --rm python:3.9-slim cat /etc/os-release you'll notice that the image is using Debian 12 Bookworm. Have you tried referencing the correct package repository for that version instead of https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/11/prod bullseye main?
